# How to (quickly) search through a long text field for a certain string (field is up to 500 chars long)

Tags: php, mysql, email, search

I have a field, called 'message' and it can hold a string of up to 500 characters in length. It's basically for an in-site inbox system.

A user has a capacity of 250 messages in their inbox.

If a user wanted to search their inbox for messages with the string 'men fashion', I would want the MySQL query to limit the query down to the 250 messages associated to that user before even searching through the 'message' field.

I would want the query to also determine and return the query results in order of how well the search string matches the content of the message. So a message that had 'men's fashion' appear thrice would appear on top; one that had 'fashion' would appear next and one that had 'men' would appear at the bottom.

How do you:

1. Make sure it doesn't drain the server
2. Do the whole sort by how well the messages match the search string thing?

Comment: you want a lot, what have you tried?

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE userId='" . mysql_escape_string($userId) . "' AND message LIKE '%" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['searchString']) . "%'";

Comment: and what's wrong with that?

Comment: @user2280657 - take a look at PDO instead (or mysqli) for security reasons. I can assure you that MySQL would not "drain the server" by such a query.

Comment: LIKE '%match%' will try to match entire word, i think in your case a partial match is better, like words that starts with xyz : LIKE '%xyz' OR ends with xyz: LIKE 'xyz%', you get the point...

Comment: Answer to second question: I guess you're looking for GROUP BY - statement? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at MySql Full Text Search function. It could return search results by relevancy.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html